# How to restrict PHP code filesystem operations on shared hosting?

Tags: php, apache, security, cpanel

I have multiple sites with different owners on my server. How can I restrict directory PHP code can work in so nobody can access others' files?

The problem is, that I am limited only to cPanel and I don't have any access to `httpd.conf`. Server is running with `lsphp`, so I can create different `php.ini` files for different directories, but I am afraid that they can be easily overwritten with `.htaccess`'s `php_value` directive I am unable to turn off.

Comment: cPanel actually handles this well.  Create separate cPanel hosting accounts for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will essentially want to restrict filesystem access for users. To achieve this, ideally you could create a separate OS user for each individual owner of a hosting and restrict their access to the specific places where they should have access.

If you are unable to do so, then you can create cPanel hosting accounts as Brad suggested in the comments section.

Comment: So... does this mean that if I create multiple cPanel accounts then their PHP code won't be able to modify and read others' files?

Comment: @user263096 the very best would be to have OS-level users directly set up, with restricted access on the file system, but if you cannot do it for some reason (restricted access, for example), then yes, CPanel hosting accounts are the second-best solution. See more here: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/securing-cpanel-on-shared-hosting.572211/

Comment: Thank you. By the way, are you sure that this link's right? It's about 2FA as far as I can see...

Comment: @user263096 sorry about that, it was an oversight on my part. Let me search for a better link.

Comment: @user263096 this one is about changing file permissions via CPanel: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/change-permissions/

Comment: Sorry, but I think that I am having problems... again... What is cPanel "hosting accounts"? Are they just simple FTP accounts? Or are we talking about some other accounts? In first case it feels that I am doing something wrong because this method doesn't work: FTP account, as at seems, are not treated as different users and have same permissions.

Comment: I suddenly understood that my hosting does not support FPM for PHP - maybe this is the source of the problem? By the way, I thought that maybe it's a good idea to create some kind of "proxy.php" (file which will require requested page with custom ini parameters) and then redirect all requests to this script? And sorry for being annoying...

Comment: @user263096 it has been a very long while since my last work involved cPanel and I do not remember these details. Unfortunately at https://documentation.cpanel.net/ I didn't see a good description about them. Do you have root credentials to the server? It would be great to solve this via ssh connection.

Comment: No, my root folder is "/home/username/". Maybe I can find the answer on cPanel forum, thank you.